# How to set the commit time with JGit?

Tags: java, commit, jgit

Is there a way to set the commit time with JGit?

I flipped through the API and found that it can only be done by modifying the local system time. I want to implement it through code. And can run normally on the win system.

Comment: @LuCio I'm so sorry about that. already edited.

Comment: As far as I understand this question it is about setting an explicit timestamp for a commit with the JGit API. This does not require changing the system time.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timestamp for a commit can be set with the `CommitCommand`. Note that name, email, and timestamp must be specified together with a `PersonIdent` object.

For example:

```java
Date date = ...
PersonIdent defaultCommitter = new PersonIdent(git.getRepository());
PersonIdent committer = new PersonIdent(defaultCommitter, date);
git.commit().setMessage("Commit with time").setCommitter(committer).call();
```

The `defaultCommitter` holds name and email as defined in the git config, the timestamp is the current system time. With the second `PersonIdent` constructor, the name and email are taken from the `defaultCommitter` and the timestamp is overridden with `date`.

Answer (score 1):

In windows the system time can be set by executing the command 'date MM-dd-yy' from the and 'Administrator' command prompt.

**Java Snippet for Windows**

```
 //Set the Date 
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");  
 String setDate = "cmd /C date "+sdf.format(dateToSet);  
 Process dateProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(setDate);  
 dateProc.waitFor();//Might take a couple of seconds

 //Set the Time  
 SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
 String setTime = "cmd /C time "+stf.format(dateToSet);  
 Process timeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(setTime);  
 timeProc.waitFor();//Might take a couple of seconds
```

This command can only be executed as an administrator. So you should run the java code with Administrator Privileges.